# How to stop background from moving while using transition in css3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```
.model__right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: Calibre-Medium,sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    
}    
.model__home,.model__project,.model__contact {
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        transition: letter-spacing 2s linear;
    }

.model__home:hover{
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

1. while using The above code while Hovering over one link ,the Top 2 links are moving to left side,
2. i want all the links to be in static and only one link which i hover want it to move on to right side  [image]

3)model_right is my parent element which belongs to right side of model(Navigation Elements)

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added width property to my parent element That restricted from moving out of my box

```
.model__right {
    display: flex;
    width:200px;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: Calibre-Medium,sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that your hover selector uses `.model__home` elements. You probably only want to select the individual list items with your `:hover` css, like so:

```css
.model_home {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  transition: letter-spacing 2s linear;
}

.model_home_item:hover {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="model_home">
  <ul>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 1</li>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 2</li>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 3</li>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If that doesn't answer your question, could you provide some more details? I'm not sure what you mean by "one link which i hover want it to move on to right side". If you are trying to have the text move to the right side on hover, you may want something more like this:

```css
.model_home {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  transition: letter-spacing 2s linear;
}

.model_home_item:hover {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="model_home">
  <ul>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 1</li>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 2</li>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 3</li>
    <li class="model_home_item">item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort